# NetSuite: turn off backorder message

Tags: netsuite

We use inventory module. We recently did a large customization to handle commitment and general ATP differently than native. We created our own alerts as part of this.

We now want to turn off the native alert that tells you an item is backordered when you are entering or editing a Sales Order.

Anyone know how to do this? I have looked in the preferences and stuff and cannot find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn these off at:

```
Home > Set Preferences > Transactions > Inventory Level Warnings
```

Comment: Thank you! I will add however that if you need to set those off for large groups of people, this is done at the role level.  At the role level, under the Preference tab, you can add "Inventory level Warnings" and set to uncheck. Note NS states: "Each preference set here is applied to new users added to this role and to existing users in this role who have not previously set that preference. Preferences that affect appearance change the look of the user interface." So if a user manually set that value, then the role change may not override them. Admin/Full access must be done by user